# How can I implode all headings of a table into a comma delimited string in Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to fetch all columns in a table and put them into a comma delimited string.

For example, I need to fetch `Col1,Col2,Col3` from the following table.

```
<table id="my_table">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Col1</th></tr>
        <tr><th>Col2</th></tr>
        <tr><th>Col3</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I do this in jQuery or Javascript?

Comment: Only `Col1,Col2,Col3` or `1,2,3...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create an array like

```
var array = $('th').map(function(){
               return $(this).text();
            }).get();
```

Then, join the array like

```
var joined = array.join(',');
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/uzpqbp6b/1/)

Also, if you want column cells, just switch the above selector from `th` to `td`

Answer (score 2):

This might work:

```
var texts = [];
$('#my_table').find('th').each(function () {
    texts.push($(this).text());
});

var result = texts.join(',');
```

Without jQuery:

```
var texts = [];
var thNodes = document.querySelectorAll('#my_table th');

for (var i = 0, nodeLength = thNodes.length; i < thNodes.length; i++) {
    texts.push(thNodes[i].innerText);
}

var result = texts.join(',');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var result=$('th').map(function(){
    return $(this).text();
}).get().join();
```

Here's how to do it in pure javascript:

```
NodeList.prototype.map=Array.prototype.map; // Fix broken implementations
var result=document.querySelectorAll('th').map(function(x){
    return x.innerText;
}).join();
```

Comment: I had edited it to have join(',') because he wants the result to be comma-seperated.

Comment: @AmmarCSE The comma isn't necessary as it is the default.

Comment: Heh, just tested and your right! Thanks for the new info! :)

Answer (score 1):

whit pure javascript you can do this:

```
<table id="my_table">
<thead>
    <tr><th>Col1</th>
    <th>Col2</th>
    <th>Col3</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div id="answer"></div>

<script>
var cols = document.querySelectorAll('#my_table thead th');

var arrColsName = Array.map(cols, function(elm){
    return elm.textContent;
});

document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = arrColsName.join(',');
</script>
```

Here is the example in jsbin: http://output.jsbin.com/zucucopehu

I hope that this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to do a small string concatenation

```
var headings=''; 
$('th').each(function(){ headings += ','+$(this).html();});
```